# Dragging the mouse down to reveal a panel? (using jQuery)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

I have a simple DIV panel that I want to slide in when the user clicks and drags a smaller tab. Here is a perfect example of what i'm looking for. Only I need to be able to do this using jQuery. ~> http://jsfiddle.net/steweb/pvdXa/

Comment: This is not an "out of the bow" solution but you could use jquery ui : http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/

Answer (score 0):

I highly recomend you go and read about jQuery UI solutions, if you want draggable content here would be a brilliant place to start: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

Answer (score 0):

This is not doable with Jquery itself. Jquery UI can do this however:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#constrain-movement look at the draggable object. you can make it only slide vertical by the movement constraint